# Lenient XML python parser: Resolve xml tags overlap

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I am looking for mistakes friendly (lenient in BeautifulSoup's terminology) python parser of "bad" XML input. The problem is tags overlap. An example input is:

```
<trn>choya - <i><b>a cholla cactus </i> lat. <i>Cylindropuntia</b></trn></i>
```

What I would like to get and XML-complient result such as (**good** result I wish)

```
<trn>choya - <b><i>a cholla cactus </i> lat. <i>Cylindropuntia</i></b></trn>
```

The `BeautifulSoup` with `html.parser` or `html5lib` gives me something else (**bad** result I don't want):

```
<trn>choya - <i><b>a cholla cactus </b></i> lat. <i>Cylindropuntia</i></trn>
```

Pay attention to the sequence of the `<i>` and `<b>` tags. If I'll mark `<i>` as italic, and `<b>` as bold, the **good** answer is

choya - ***a cholla cactus*** **lat.** ***Cylindropuntia***

and the **bad** answer is

choya - ***a cholla cactus*** lat. *Cylindropuntia*

I tried also old `tidyhtml`, couldn't get a necessary result. And for new `tidy-html5` could not find a python interface.
Can you help me please, either

- to find a a parser the can do this job
- if there isn't such, to advice an algorithm or any source of knowledge that concerns these kinds of algorithms

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`html.parser.HTMLParser` is good at parsing tag soup, and the SAX `XMLGenerator` class has a convenient API to generate XML based on events.

Not all of the bits are implemented here, especially not the "rigidness"/"weight" constraints for the tags (right now all we do is just close the tag with what we expect it to be to make nesting correct), but the basic idea seems to work.

The output is

```
<trn>choya - <i><com>a cholla cactus </com> lat. <i>Cylindropuntia</i></i> native to US</trn>
```

which is valid XML, nesting-wise.

Good luck!

---

```py
import html.parser
import io
from xml.sax.saxutils import XMLGenerator


class Reconstructor(html.parser.HTMLParser):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.op_stream = []
        self.tag_stack = []

    def handle_startendtag(self, tag, attrs):
        self.op_stream.append(('startendtag', (tag, attrs)))

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        self.op_stream.append(('starttag', (tag, attrs)))
        self.tag_stack.append(tag)

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        expected_tag = self.tag_stack[-1]
        if tag != expected_tag:
            print('mismatch closing <{}>, expected <{}>'.format(tag, expected_tag))
            # TODO: implement logic to figure out the correct order for the tags here
            #       and reorder tag_stack accordingly.
        stack_tag = self.tag_stack.pop(-1)
        self.op_stream.append(('endtag', (stack_tag, tag)))

    def handle_charref(self, name):
        self.op_stream.append(('charref', (name,)))

    def handle_entityref(self, name):
        self.op_stream.append(('entityref', (name,)))

    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.op_stream.append(('data', (data,)))

    def handle_comment(self, data):
        self.op_stream.append(('comment', (data,)))

    def handle_decl(self, decl):
        self.op_stream.append(('decl', (decl,)))

    def handle_pi(self, data):
        self.op_stream.append(('pi', (data,)))

    def generate_xml(self):
        stream = io.StringIO()
        xg = XMLGenerator(stream, encoding='utf-8')
        for op, args in self.op_stream:
            if op in ('startendtag', 'starttag'):
                tag, attrib = args
                xg.startElement(tag, dict(attrib))
                if op == 'startendtag':
                    xg.endElement(tag)
            elif op == 'endtag':
                tag = args[0]
                xg.endElement(tag)
            elif op == 'data':
                xg.characters(args[0])
            else:
                raise NotImplementedError('Operator not implemented: %s' % op)
        xg.endDocument()
        return stream.getvalue()


xr = Reconstructor()
xr.feed('<trn>choya - <i><com>a cholla cactus </i> lat. <i>Cylindropuntia</com></trn> native to US</i>')
y = xr.generate_xml()
print(y)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The output, however, is a **bad** result. As I said, BeautifulSoup with the html.parser gives me the same. I will shorten and clear the questing to stress the issue.

Comment: But this result is customizable – see the TODO comment in the code.

Comment: I see... Yes, the right `handle_endtag` logic function will be the answer to my question. Thank you, I'll comment again when I'll succeed (or fail).